# mysql group_concat distinct + group by and a where condition

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this which works fine until I need to add a condition on colA

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colA) as colA, CONCAT (colB,colC,colD) AS group1 FROM tablename GROUP BY group1`

colA will return things like:

```
"AH,LO,CE"
"AH,LO"
"AH,DE"
"AH"
"LO,CE,DF"
"LO,DF"
```

I need to add the condition to the query where a specific colA value must be present such as "AH" however when I do this the results do not the other concat(distinct on colA so I end up with

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colA) as colA, CONCAT (colB,colC,colD) AS group1 FROM tablename WHERE colA = 'AH' GROUP BY group1`

```
"AH"
"AH"
"AH"
"AH"
```

I want the other records concatenated like it shows in the first result but adding that one of the matching records must include the value, but as long as one matches then it still brings in all the others that match the group on Group1

```
"AH,LO,CE"
"AH,LO"
"AH,DE"
"AH"
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` and `FIND_IN_SET` like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colA) as colA, CONCAT(colB, colC, colD) AS group1
FROM tablename
GROUP BY group1
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('AH', colA)
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u2dNT44D4mqYDeBNBwtaXT/0)